# Generate innerHTML at the start of an element

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I want to generate HTML-code at the beginning of an existing element.

This is the existing HTML-element:

```
<div id="container">
  <p>end of the element</p>
</div>
```

With my current solution I add the generated element beneath the existing content:

```
document.getElementById(container).innerHTML += "<p>start of the element</p>";
```

How to add content above the existing content of an element with `innerHTML`?

Comment: `document.getElementById(container).innerHTML = "<p>start of the element</p>" + document.getElementById(container).innerHTML;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prepend `document.getElementById('container').innerHTML` to the assignment and remove `+=` shorthand:

```js
document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "<p>start of the element</p>" + document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p>end of the element</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a relatively new function especially for that: `insertAdjacentHTML`. Which has four options: before the opening tag (`beforeBegin`), right after the opening tag (`afterBegin`), just before the closing tag (`beforeEnd`), and after the closing tag (`afterEnd`). In your case:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>First paragraph in the code, but should become second after the Javascript fired.</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('div').insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin','<p>Second paragraph in the code, but should become first.</p>')
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might work

```
var newItem = document.createElement("p");
newItem.innerHTML = "start of the element";
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var currentItem = document.getElementById("container").firstChild;
container.insertBefore(newItem, currentItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$('#container').prepend("<p>start of element</p>");
</script>
```

```js
$('#addText').click(function() {
  $('#container').prepend("<p>Prepended Text:" +
    $('#textToPrepend').val() +
    "</p>");
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="textToPrepend" /><br/>
<button id="addText">Add text to div</button>
<div id="container">
  <p> Div Container
    <p/>
</div>
```